# Как анализировать внешний трафик на VPS?

Tags: сеть, трафик, linux

Есть VPS и на нем крутится сайт. Совсем недавно хостинг прислал счет на превышение лимита внешнего трафика на 300Гб. По лог-файлу apache, трафик с самим веб-сервером составляет 100-200 Мб. Соответственно, необходимо искать "что" качает и сколько, а самое главное откуда.Хостинг, как и провайдер, такой информации не предоставляет. Т.е. в идеале для меня необходимо получить информацию такого вида:Таблица:

[Мой IP] [домен или ip к которому обращались] [Кол-во полученного/отправленного объема]

IP - domain.com/ip - Traffic

Comment: На сервере стоит Debian

Comment: Вам в прошлом или будущем?

Comment: в будущем. Т.к. проблема не устранена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно настроить [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/). Не сложно. Еще как вариант настроить на логирование iptables.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner username -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1iptables -A INPUT -m connmark --mark 1 -j LOGiptables -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 1 -j LOG
```

Comment: настроил так iptraf -i eth0 -B -L /var/log/iptraf/traf.logА как узнать какой домен по какому ip?

Comment: не понял, вы про DNS ?

Comment: Например, host -t a hashcode.ru покажет все IP этого домена или через dig, nslookup. Верно? А мне необходима статистика обмена трафиком с конкретными доменами. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Так не получится потому что обмен идет по ip  адресам а не по доменным именам.